# How to receive calls using ATAPI JULMAR library on PC

Tags: c#, telephony, tapi

I am searching on internet for last three weeks how to answer call using C# 
but couldn't solve my problem 
however I managed to dial call using this

http://mukarrammukhtar.wordpress.com/creation-of-phone-caller-application/

Can any body suggest a simple solution like given above.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would have used the [Turbopower TAPI component](http://tpapro.sourceforge.net/) for Delphi and write wrapper method for the Delphi generated code. This is not as bad as it looks. 
Turbopower components are completely free which is a bonus. In addition there is not much of Delphi coding involved either[Quite similar to C# as both have been the brain-child of Anders Hejlsberg] . A few years ago I was stalk in similar situation  of yours and I followed the exact advice I am recommending you and I am happily ever after.

Comment: Bro I couldn't get the understanding of the given link